# How to get the inode structure of the /proc/pid/fd/n file of an opened file in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, vfs

For a given **fd number**, I know I can get the inode structure of the opened file by calling [`fget_raw`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/file.c#L723). But what I actually want to get is the inode structure of the file `/proc/pid/fd/n`, which is actually another file in procfs.

This may be done by calling [`path_lookup`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/fs/namei.c#L1093) with a spliced path of `proc/pid/fd/n`, but I think it's not the best way of doing this. Is there a way to get the inode directly from a fd number or a [file structure](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L915)? I think such process should occur when a `close` syscall is made, because a close call should get the `/proc/pid/fs/n` entry in order to delete it, but I can't locate related code.

I'm doing this because I want to get the time when the socket was opened.

Comment: An inode for `/proc/pid/fd/<n>` stores (internally) only **fd number** for corresponded file. Accessing a file by that number is performed via `struct files_struct` object. See e.g. [fs/proc/fd.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/fs/proc/fd.c#L34).

Comment: Seems that the inode of entries in procfs is instantiated on-the-fly when the first access is made. So the ctime is the first time the entry was accessed, not the corresponded socket was opened.

Comment: Yes, many entries in procfs (under `/proc`) are instantiated on-the-fly.